# include a verificationToken or clientSigningSecret to verify incoming Events API webhooks

Tags: node.js, botframework, slack

I am trying to develop a chatbot using microsoft bot framework and I am also using botbuilder-adaptor-slack npm package to connect it to slack. This is following code which I have written in javascript:

```
const restify =  require('restify');
const { BotFrameworkAdapter, UserState, MemoryStorage } = require('botbuilder');

const  {SlackAdapter} = require('botbuilder-adapter-slack')
const WelcomeBot = require('./functions/welcomebot')

const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
const userState = new UserState(memoryStorage);
const bot = new WelcomeBot.WelcomeBot(userState);
const adapter = new SlackAdapter({clientSigningSecret:process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    verificationToken:process.env.verificationToken, 
    botToken:process.env.SLACK_TOKEN,
    oauthVersion: 'v2'
});

adapter.onTurnError = async(context,error) => {

}

let server = restify.createServer()
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());


server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
        adapter.processActivity(req, res, async(context) => {

            console.log(req.body)
            await bot.run(context);
        })
    
})

server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});
```

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run the code.

[image]

Can somebody please help me with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing your auth information. You need to either:

1. Run in debug mode with a breakpoint on `const adapter = new SlackAdapter...` and ensure that `process.env.<variable>`, or
2. Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(process.env, null, 2))`

to ensure your environment variables (`process.env.CLIENT_SECRET`, `process.env.verificationToken`, and `process.env.SLACK_TOKEN`) are actually being set and exist.

If they are, then one of them is incorrect.

If they are not set or don't exist in `process.env`, you likely need to:

1. Create a `.env` file with:

```
CLIENT_SECRET=<yourClientSecret>
verificationToken=<yourVerificationToken>
SLACK_TOKEN=<yourSlackToken>
```

*Note: Capitalization matters!*

2. Add the following to your code, just after your `import` statements:

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
// Import required bot configuration.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
dotenv.config({ path: ENV_FILE });
```

*I'd wager your issue is just that you're missing this code*

Comment: Thank you. After making the suggested changes the code worked.